# printing postgres data to html with node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to print out some users from a pg database. in an index.js file I have the following:

```
function list(callback) {
pg.connect(cstr, function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            client.query('select fname from users', function(err, result) {
                // Ends the "transaction":
                done();
                // Disconnects from the database:
                client.end();
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    callback(result.rows);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and in my app.js I have the following:

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {

  db.list(function(data){ 
    console.log(data); 
    res.send(data); 
  }); 

});
```

I know that its getting the users because it is outputting it to the console. But when I reload the page I get "No Data received".

console.log outputs the following:

```
[ { fname: 'Frank' },
  { fname: 'Jake' },
  { fname: 'Cristiano' },
  { fname: 'Lionel' },
  { fname: 'Wayne' } ]
```

I need to output that in a table form on my browser but I don't know how to get it to send data.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with -

`db.list(function(data){ 
    console.log(data);
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    res.end(data); 
  });`

Also, when you send the data to html, you need to use some javascript template engine like `ejs` to render data in html.

More about ejs is [here](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)

Hope this may help you.

Thanks